# Why are airport firetrucks painted yellow green?

Tags: emergency, airport

In my city, most of, if not all of the fire-trucks that serve city emergencies are **red**, just like this one:

[image: Regular Fire-truck]

But every time that I see an airport emergency that requires the fire-fighters, I see this kind of truck:

[image: Airport Fire-truck]

Is there a reason why the airport trucks are yellow-green and not red?

Comment: [not all of them](https://www.google.be/search?q=airport+firetruck&num=100&safe=off&source=lnms&tbm=isch)

Comment: in Italy they are red

Comment: Using the German term ["Flughafenfeuerwehr"](https://www.google.de/search?q=flughafenfeuerwehr&source=lnms&tbm=isch), you get a quite different selection (although the more modern ones tend to have *some* lime in there). A thing to note are the *blue* flashing lights, which are standard on (and limited to!) German emergency vehicles. Looking at how [German traffic reacts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=02Ak1eIyj3M) to a simple flashing blue light (and the two-tone "Martinshorn" siren), I always wondered why US emergency vehicles bother with that sound-and-lightshow of theirs. ;-)

Comment: @DevSolar You could blast Twisted Sister from our emergency vehicles while running a Pink Floyd laser show on top and nobody would move out of the way, but in true American fashion we operate on the principle that more/bigger/louder is better. (Just for fun try driving past one of our police cruisers at night on an unlit highway when it's got its [roof-rack](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Uqxma.jpg) lit. I've had to pull over because their lights completely destroyed my night vision.)

Comment: @voretaq7: That's exactly what I wanted to hint at: Less might be more. You simply don't see any blue lights in traffic *other* than in emergency vehicles, and you don't hear that horn anywhere else either. So if you *do* see / hear it (which is comparatively rare), you *get the heck out of the way* because you *know* it's not some redneck in his pickup or the pizza deliveries, but *real* emergency. (And *boy* would you get in trouble if you'd mount blue lights on a pizza taxi...)

Comment: @DevSolar Not limited to Germany ^^ ["Brandweerauto's"](http://static.webshopapp.com/shops/029999/files/009025138/brandweerauto.jpg) have them in blue as well. Sometimes the cars are [yellow/white](http://members.home.nl/e.ubels/images/brw%2041.JPG).

Comment: For the example in the picture, the vast majority of Miami-Dade county emergency vehicles are that color for visibility reasons, not just the ones at the airport.  Both the red and yellow-green varieties are ignored by the local population with the same intensity.

Comment: @DevSolar At least in the state where I live, blue lights are illegal for anyone but police vehicles and forward-visible red lights are illegal for non-emergency vehicles. While I won't say I never see other vehicles with blue lights, it is pretty rare and I don't think I've ever seen flashing ones here on a non-police vehicle.

Comment: @voretaq7 Yeah, the new LED light bars tend to be really high intensity, especially the blue ones. They really do hurt to look at. Even some of the new LED turn signals/brake lights have intensities that hurt to see, especially at night. Having said that, traffic moving for emergency vehicles is probably more of a regional thing. Here in the South, most people actually do get out of the way when feasible (though this probably has localized exceptions and the state of Florida doesn't count as the South. - lol)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Because yellow/green has been shown to be more visible than red, especially in low light conditions.  Yellow/green is also more easily identified by people with colour blindness and other visual disorders.

It's the same reason that safety vests are yellow/green.

[This article gives some good references.](http://www.apa.org/action/resources/research-in-action/lime.aspx)

Comment: So now the question is, why are regular firetrucks painted red?

Comment: @DavidGrinberg Good question, not sure.  I've read that it's a mixture of tradition and because people associate red with fire engines.  There's psychology in there somewhere I'm sure.

Comment: Regular fire trucks in my city are painted yellow and have been for as long as I can remember. The link talks about people recognizing the color as  fire truck too.... the main factor is probably just tradition in whatever locality you're in.

Comment: If you have an Iphone, ask siri "Why are firetrucks red"... She'll answer in the best way :)

Comment: @GabrielBrito Well, I'm lucky enough not to own an iPhone ;), but I assume that it's the same answer that Google Now gives you about 4 wheels and 8 people?

Comment: @Simon I think those virtual assistants are talking to each other... hahaha yep :)

Comment: The article you cite seems to be saying that it's the fluorescence that increases visibility, not the green-ness. This is unsurprising, since fluorescent objects are brighter than objects that merely reflect the same colour: fluorescence is the absorption of ultra-violet which is then re-emitted as visible light.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Which at night, is mostly missing.  Our eyes are very bad at seeing red at night.  It's why astronomers use red torches.  Yellow/green is the most visible colour in daylight and at night and overall; yellow is the most visible colour to the human eye. http://www.usroads.com/journals/aruj/9702/ru970203.htm

Comment: @DavidGrinberg Fire services in the US have been hotly debating the color of fire trucks for years. Many are no longer red because red is a lousy color for visibility, while others remain red because tradition outweighs _many_ things in the fire service.

Comment: @Simon And they talk about retroreflective strips for night-time visibility. I don't see anything in the article you cite in your answer that says that non-fluorescent yellow-green would be better than red.

Comment: @DavidRicherby http://www.colormatters.com/color-and-vision/color-and-vision-matters, and many others obtained with a simple Google search.  The simple reason is that yellow activates both the red and green cones in the eye.

Answer (score 8):

While Simon has told you about why ALL Fire Engines SHOULD better be yellow/green, not red, he did not tell you why all Airport Fire Trucks you have seen are yellow, and all normal Fire Trucks you have seen are red.

PBS's "Firehouse Primer" on the history of red fire engines:

> Before firefighting was a paid profession, most communities were served by volunteer fire departments. These firemen didn't have much money to spend on upkeep, and at the time red was the least expensive color of paint. Red wasn't the only color used, however. Before it merged with the force in Manhattan, the Brooklyn Fire Department painted its apparatus a two-tone green to distinguish them from the red apparatus of the Metropolitan Fire Department. Today, there are still different colored fire engines, but red is the most common color out of tradition.

I don't know whether this is true or just an anecdote, but it's a nice story nevertheless.

While in the US, where fire fighting is a local issue, you will see yellow fire engines with some fire dept's (mostly in rural areas, I guess it's because you have long unlighted stretches of street there), in your native Brazil, the central government has decided to use red for all engines. This is the same in my native Germany, where the color mandated by law for fire trucks used on public streets has changed slightly over the years, from a dark red over a orangeish red to a retroreflecting orange-red. The Swiss, where fire fighting is a local issue as well, have mostly switched to yellow fire engines for visibility reasons. So I guess that you have only been to red-engine territory until now.

For airports, it's a different issue: Unless ordered otherwise, Oshkosh's (the US market leader) airport fire engine lineup is painted green/yellow. Rosenbauer (big player in Europe) on the other hand has a red lineup. While you can order other colors, most customers stick to  the default. So my best guess is that you haven't attended any plane evacuations in Europe until now.

Comment: Ah... so kind of like the color of tractors... John Deer green, Claas lime, Newholland blue...

Comment: No, no , no, no. Because they have eight wheels and four people on them, and four plus eight makes twelve, and there are twelve inches in a foot, and one foot is a ruler, and Queen Elizabeth was a ruler, and Queen Elizabeth was also a ship, and the ship sailed the seas, and there were fish in the seas, and fish have fins, and the Finns fought the Russians, and the Russians are red, and fire trucks are always “Russian” around, so that’s why fire trucks are red!

Comment: @Simon Nice anecdote, but I think you left out half of the story. Did you run into a comment's character limit?

Answer (score 8):

It's because it is the color specified by the Federal Aviation Administration and the only color of firefighting vehicle they will participate in funding.

[Advisory Circular AC 150/5210-5D](http://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/150_5210_5d.pdf) states

> **Aircraft Rescue and Fire Fighting (ARFF) Vehicles.** Yellowish-green is the vehicle color standard.

and

> **APPLICATION.**  The Federal Aviation Administration (FAA) recommends the guidelines and standards in this Advisory Circular for vehicles operating in the airport AOA. In general, use of this AC is not mandatory. 
>   ***However***, use of this AC is mandatory for vehicles funded with federal grant monies through the Airport Improvement Program (AIP) and/or with revenue from the Passenger Facility Charges (PFC) Program. See Grant Assurance No. 34, “Policies, Standards, and Specifications,” and PFC Assurance No. 9, “Standard and Specifications.”  [emphasis in original]

Comment: Well, this explains why exactly Oshkosh's and their U.S. competitors' lineups use yellowish-green as default color. Good find!

Comment: to add acurved ball to the debate.in the uk,I worked as a locomotive driver and anyone trackside has to wear a dayglow orange hi viz jacket. for a trial period,they issued yellow/green jackets,and loco drivers had to give feedback.i can say,at certain light conditions,yellow/green was poor to see compared to dayglow orange,and the uks railways kept that colour. so perhaps fire trucks should be painted orange?

Answer (score 0):

Humans evolved in sunlight, which produces mostly yellow-green light frequencies. Therefore, we are most sensitive to the yellowish green part of the visible light spectrum. This is why safety vests are yellow-green. Airport firetrucks and new firetrucks are slowly starting to be painted yellow-green instead of the traditional red. There has been research which shows that firetrucks of this color are less accident prone than red ones.
Hope this was helpful (: